# Uncommitted changes "collapse arrow" color VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In this image the white background of the collapsed `try` block is the setting:

`"workbench.colorCustomizations": { "editor.foldBackground": "#ffffff" }`

But, what I can't find anywhere or guess at correctly is how to change the color of the little red arrow inbetween lines 6 and 7? This is where there are uncommitted changes that you can view/revert, like the last two images. I just don't want red because that is my error highlight color and I'm revamping a huge project to pull all PPI out and it is starting to drive me crazy looking like there are thousands of errors when it is just uncommitted code.

[image: collapse change block arrow color]

[image: uncommitted code highlighted]

[image: ability to revert code]

Comment: That is specifically the deletion icon BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `colorCustomization`:

`editorGutter.deletedBackground`  Editor gutter background color for lines that are deleted.

from the end of https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors

There are also these:

````
editorGutter.modifiedBackground: Editor gutter background color for lines that are modified.
editorGutter.addedBackground: Editor gutter background color for lines that are added.```
````

Comment: It's a beautiful thing! `editorGutter.deletedBackground` did it for me, but the other two are useful for my desired VSCode look. No more red for changes!